# using jQuery widget factory, creating treeview including ui.sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get my head around using jQuery widget factory to create a plugin. I'm in the progress of creating an simple treeview plugin where I would like to implement the ui.sortable widget and for that i do something like :

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("cms.treeview", $.ui.sortable, {
        // Default options.
        options: {
            useSorting: false
        },

        // Default constructor.
        _create: function(){
            // creating treeview code goes here

            // if useSorting is set to true set sorting
            if (this.options.useSorting){
                // HOW WOULD I CALL THE SORTING HERE
            }
        U
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Now when i add ui.sortable to the $.widget("cms.treeview", $.ui.sortable, { }); declariation i get all the options from the sortable widget but how would i call it in my code and make sure to have all what I need?

/Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
$.widget("cms.treeview", $.ui.sortable, {
    // Default options.
    options: {
        useSorting: false,
        makeMeSortable:$.noop
    },

    elementToMakeSortable:null,
    // Default constructor.
    _create: function(){
        // creating treeview code goes here
        this.elementToMakeSortable = $(document.createElement('ULorWhateverElement'));
        // if useSorting is set to true set sorting
        if (this.options.useSorting){
            // HOW WOULD I CALL THE SORTING HERE
            this._trigger('makeMeSortable', null, { elementToBeSortable:this.elementToMakeSortable});
        }
});
})(jQuery)
```

then, on your page you have something like this:

```
var yourTreeviewWidgetInstance = $('#someElement').treeview({
    useSorting:true,
//this gets called from treeview widget if userSorting=true
    makeMeSortable: function (event, elementToMakeSortable) { 
    $(elementToMakeSortable).sortable();
}
```

PS.
I haven't tested the code, I'm writing it from my head. Just giving you idea of the design.

Comment: This seems to be working as it should, for both my treeview and sorting, Thanks ;o)

Comment: Nice! I'm glad to hear:)

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle it doesn't sound good having widgets being aware of one another. Usually, that is what 'options as functions' are used for.
For example, here you can see 2 widgets communicating:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404085.aspx

So, in your example, what you would do is to setup one option named 'makeMeSortable' e.g.:

```
// Default options.
options: {
useSorting: false,
makeMeSortable:$.noop
}
```

then you would do something like:

```
if (this.options.useSorting){
// HOW WOULD I CALL THE SORTING HERE
this._trigger('makeMeSortable', null, { elementToBeSortable: this.yourElementToSort})
}
```

and finally, when making an instance of your widget you would assign a function to makeMeSortable option. that function would recieve your element to be sorted and call ui.sortable widget.

Comment: Could you please show me how I would call this from my webpage then? How do I set options to the sortable widget?